# Unknown backup error - Déjà Dup

Tags: 17.10, backup, deja-dup

I am not able to back up my Ubuntu 17.10 to an FTP server through the system default program (Déjà Dup). Attempting to run the program reports a crash due to an unknown error. I have already checked the server and my user has the necessary permissions, including the backup gets to mount the drive.

Comment: Can you check ~/.cache/deja-dup/ and add any relevant information there to your question? You may also get helpful output from running `DEJA_DUP_DEBUG=1 deja-dup --backup` from command line

Comment: Please edit your question and put a title in English. Show the exact command you launch and the error exactly as displayed.